# Reproject vector layer with OGR and python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, ogr

I want to reproject a vector Geopackage from WGS (4326) to UTM (32605) using OGR and python. However, after running the code below the feature geometry and data extent is still in degrees and not in meters.  I'm using the following code from <pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html?highlight=reproject>.

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr
import os

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('GPKG')

# input SpatialReference
inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

# output SpatialReference
outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(32605)

# create the CoordinateTransformation
coordTrans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)

# get the input layer
inDataSet = driver.Open(r'IN_PATH')
inLayer = inDataSet.GetLayer()

# create the output layer
outputShapefile = r'OUT_PATH'
if os.path.exists(outputShapefile):
    driver.DeleteDataSource(outputShapefile)
outDataSet = driver.CreateDataSource(outputShapefile)
outLayer = outDataSet.CreateLayer("reproject",outSpatialRef, geom_type=ogr.wkbMultiPolygon)

# add fields
inLayerDefn = inLayer.GetLayerDefn()
for i in range(0, inLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
    fieldDefn = inLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i)
    outLayer.CreateField(fieldDefn)

# get the output layer's feature definition
outLayerDefn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()

# loop through the input features
inFeature = inLayer.GetNextFeature()
while inFeature:
    # get the input geometry
    geom = inFeature.GetGeometryRef()
    # reproject the geometry
    geom.Transform(coordTrans)
    # create a new feature
    outFeature = ogr.Feature(outLayerDefn)
    # set the geometry and attribute
    outFeature.SetGeometry(geom)
    for i in range(0, outLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
        outFeature.SetField(outLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i).GetNameRef(), inFeature.GetField(i))
    # add the feature to the GPKG
    outLayer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
    # dereference the features and get the next input feature
    outFeature = None
    inFeature = inLayer.GetNextFeature()

# Save and close the GPKG
inDataSet = None
outDataSet = None
```

The code runs and creates a new Geopackage file however, the reprojected geometry stays in degrees and the extent of the data is in degrees instead of meters. The reprojected CRS is correct (EPSG:32605)
[image: extent in degrees, unit in meters]

[image: output crs]

I don't see any additional errors reported when running the script.
GDAL version = GDAL 3.2.3, released 2021/04/27
Any idea where it goes wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: what is not working? is there an error message?

Comment: The feature geometry is not converted from degrees (EPSG:4326) to meters (epsg:32605).

Comment: The cookbook is a bit outdated and reprojections doesn't work that way now. Include a `print(geom.Transform(coordTrans)` to see the problem.